# How to show a picture of Tow Mater when I typo "git checkout mater"

Tags: shell, git, zsh

During the course of my day, I occasionally mistype when moving between git branches and attempt to checkout the unknown branch `mater` when I really want to move back to `master`.

When this occurs, I'd like my terminal to display an ascii-art rendering of the character Tow Mater from the Pixar film, "Cars" as a gentle rebuke to my errant fingers.

I already have a great rendering, but I'm not sure how to create an alias for an entire `git co mater` (or `git checkout mater`) command, since the real `git` wants to take precedence.

Thoughts? Do I need to make `git` a shell function that looks for my typo and otherwise delegates out to the real `git`?

Thanks for reading. Here's Mater:

```
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((... ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((//( .,.********/*,,.(/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//..*****//////(///////(((((*./((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((///((/(.**/////*,,.....................,*//(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/./%(.,***/*,....,,*/((##############((/*,,/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/ */(/*//*,..,*(#%%%#((((##%%%%%%%%##((/(((*./((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((( / (( (.*****,,..*(#%%%%&%&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&%***/(// (   .....(/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//.*/*.,,*,,,,..,,/(####((((#%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%,,//*,,,.....,,.*//((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((,((#/*,,,,...,,//(((#%&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@(***/( /(.,**/(((//((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((.......,***//**,,,.,,*///(%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@,*(//.*(####/(/#/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((/( .(/**,,,***,,,,....,,,,,*//(&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*,*.//*/#%%##/((#,/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((/(/(// (((((((((((( ..,/(/*//(((((//,.. .,,.,,,*,,,*(#&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&(**//(,/((##(*/%%(/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((/(    .**.... ..*****,,,,,,**/**//(##((//,..,,,,,.,,,,,//(#&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&*,*(//,//(((*,#&///((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((/(( ,,..,***,****,*......//(((((***/**/((((///,..,,,,,.,,,,*(((#%&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#**.((/*/((/*,*#&/ ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((( ,.,(//(((/,,**,*/*///.,**,,,...**//,*(((((/*...,,,,,.,,,,*(((#%&&@@@@%(/(#@@@@@@@@@/*,,,*(@@@@@@@@@@@@%,** (.*/(/*,,/&&//(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((//..*/((((((/(.,,,,,.*/*,*,,,**(/ ,**//,,///((/*...,,,,,.,,,*,/((#%&&@@%/*,.***(@@@@@*,  .,,#@@@@@@@@@@@@/**(//,//(/*.*(#/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((.(../(((((((/(/(.... ,**,...,,,....,***,,//*////...,,,,,.,,,*,/(##%%&@@((,.   ,*&@@@@&%#(   ,,#@@@@&%%######(/*,(/*////,*//#/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((/(..((( ...,.../((..,..*/***.,..,.,,***,,***////,..,,,,,,,,,*,*(##%%&@@%#%(,,**/@@@@@@@%#%%#//#############(///*(/,*///,,***/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((/(//.,,..*****../(/(,,*..*//,,*,...,***,,,*,*///,,.,,,,,,,,,***/(((((((((((#####%%%%%&&&%#((((((((//////////****...,**,.*/*./(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((,,*(((/*.,,*.,,,,*.,.,***,,,**,*//*,..,,,,,,,,**,,,******************///////***///////((///(((((((#(***////.((((((( //.,,(//*(//*.(/((((((((((
((((((//(.. (//,.../((((/(.,,**..,,,,*.***,,,,*,,***,..,,,,,,,****,****************////((((((((///************/*///(#(//*,,*/, /(..**//*/(((/*,**(((*(/((((((((
((((((/... ./.,..,,/(((((//(.,*/,...,*//*,,,,,*****//***,,,,**//**///**,*****////((//***//(/*,,****/////((((###(((((##(/*,,,**,**,,,,,,,//**.....,,/((/((((((((
(((((/(..,*,,.   .//(((((((//(..,**..,**,,,.,..,....,,,*****//***//*,,,*///////**,,,,**/(/,,**/((((///***,,,...      .***,,,,.......,*,.*/,,. .,,,,*(/(((((((((
((((((/*     *(///((((((((((((((/,*.(.,,**,,. .,....,*****////**//*********,//*(#(((/,**(/*,,..           .,,**,.,,*******,,         .,.,**,...***,*((/((((((((
(((((((///((/(((((((((((((((((((/(/,*(**,,,,. .*,,,***//////***************,//%&%%&&&(***,  ..,..,,,,,,,..,,....,,,,,,,,*********////**/,,//*******(/(/((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((*,,(.*,,. ..,****///*****,,,*//**/////*,/(&%#%&&(//*,,,,,,,,,,********,,,,,,,,,*******//(///****///*,*((/*/((/(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((.,,*,,,*,..  ..**//*,,,,,,*****,,**,***,*/#%%###%(((/***////**//******/*///////////////////////****/((*,,,,,,,*/(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/(.,,,,,,**,...,******,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/(#((/(((///****//(((####%#########%%#########((#((//(((((###(//****//(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((,,*******,.,//******,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,***,,*/(((///(((##%%%%%&%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#%%%%#####((//((###((/*//(/*/(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/  //,******,*,********,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,****/(((#####((/((((####%###%%#%%%%%%&&%%%%%%%#####(((((#(//((///((*((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((/(/    ,,,,,*******************,,,,,,,,,,,,***************//(((#####(//***//((#####%%%%##%%%%%&&&%%%%#####((/(((((((((/(///,/(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((/(.,,,,,,****,*************,,,,,***,,,,,,,****,*************//(####%#(/*,***///((######((/////((#%%%%%&&%%#(/////(((((((((##(*/(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((//*,,,******************,,*,,,,,,,,***********,************//((((###(//*..*/////////****//(##%%(/.,*/(#%%##((/////////((((#(((/.(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((,**********************,,,*****************,**************//((##(((/(/*.  .,,,**/(#**&@@@@@@@@@&.,/,*//((////////((((((((/((/(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((/,***********************,,**************,    .,*,,*******///((##(((((/(/, .,//((#%/&@@@@@@@@@@*.%@@@&(/,,/((((((((((((#(//(#/ ((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((,,************************,**///////****.       .,***********/((((##((/(#(, .,,,,..   /%@@@@@@@@@/ /@@@@@@@(((((((((//((((////#*(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((,,******,,..,,************,*/////////**,. ........,*/******//((((####(((##/.           *@@@@@@@&%, .%@@@@@&(((((((/(((///((//(#//((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((,,***,    ,...,***********,*////*//*/*,,...........*//****////((((###(((#%(*,           ,//,,.        ..,*/((((##((/(/////////((,,.((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((/***,   ,,,,...,**********,*////***//*,,...........,*********/((######(##%#/*,                        .,*/((((((((/(((((///*,*/###(*/((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((***. .,,,,,,...,*********,*////****/*,,.......,,,,,,**,***///(((#####((###((**                      ,((///////(((//(/////***////((//((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((/*, .,,,,,,,....*********,,*//*****//*,...,,**,,,,,,**,,,**///((########%##(/**.                   *////////////(////***///***//((((/(((((
((((((((((((((((((((/,,,.....,,.,,...,**,,****,,*//**///**,,..,**,,,,,..,,,,*****////(((((((#####(/,,,.....            */////////////*****//*****//(((((/((((((
((((((((((((((((((((/.,.......,,,,,..,,,,,*****,,*,,,,,,,*,,.,*,,,,,.....,,*(/(///////((((((######(*,,*(%&&&//((#(((#//***///////*****////**///(((/((//,(/(((((
(((((((((((((((((/(**,,,,,...,*,,,,,,,,,**,,**,..,......   .,,,,,...,,,,..,***////((#(((//////(#(((//,,,*/##/////////,,**********//////////(///////**/(#.((((((
((((((((((((((((((//....,,,,,**,,...,,..  .......       ...,,,,,,..****,,,,,*,,**///((((#((//*/((((//**,,,,,**//**,,,,****,**//****//////(((//*,,,*//*/(/./((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((,,,,,**,,,.,,,,.  ....,............,,,,....,,..,..,,*******((((//////////((((/**,,,......,,,,**/(((////**////(((((/*....,.,*////(*(((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((*,*****.,,...,,,.  ....,........ ...,,,,....,,,........,,***((((#((//(((//(##(###(////////((((/((((/////////////*..  .....,.****///(/(((
((((((((((((((((((((((//,****//,,..,,,,.  ....,........, .,,,,,....,,..,,..,,...   ..**//((#((((((((((#(((///////(//(((((((((((///*,... ......,..,.,****//(/(((
((((((((((((((((((((((//,,*****,....,,..  ....,....(*,,/(..,**,,...,,,.....,...    .,,,...,*//(#((((/(((((((///(((((((((((((//*..    ..    ........,,**,**(/(((
(((((((((((((((((((((((/,,***,,........  ........./(///(//,,*,,,,....,,,,,,,...   .,,,,,.......,*/((((((((#(((/((#((((//*,.......    ..........,...,,,,,*..((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((,,,,,,... ....   .  .... *(((((((//.,**,,,......,,... .....,*,,,.....   ..  .  ..,,,,,... .,****...........   ............,,,,,,,*/((((
                        ..,...                    ......    .,,,,,,....         .,,,,,......       (//////(/(//((((((((((/..,,.....       .....,,,,,,,,,(/(((((
                                               ...............,,*,,,,,....    ..,,,,...........,*, (/(((((((((((((((((((///...,..........,,,,,,,,,,....(/((((((
                                                               .,,,,,,,.......,,,........       .           (((((//(/((((((/*..........,,,,,,,...... /(((((((((
.                                                                ...............                                    .. /(((((((      ......       ,((/(((((((((
      ..                                                              ....                                                  .........            ....((((((((((
((((/////////////((((*.,                                                       ...........                                                   ./((((((/(((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((//(((** .                                                                          .. .,////(/(((((((((((((((((((////(/(((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//((((/(/((((((((((((((((((/(/////////(/////((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your shell's setup file, define a function to wrap `git`, and then alias `git` to that function. Echo out a HEREDOC showing our faithful mater, and then be nice and switch over to `master` cuz that's what you wanted all along.

In your .zshrc:

```bsh
git_yer_maters () {
    if [[ $argv = "co mater" ]]; then
        cat << EOF
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((... ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((//( .,.********/*,,.(/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//..*****//////(///////(((((*./((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((///((/(.**/////*,,.....................,*//(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/./%(.,***/*,....,,*/((##############((/*,,/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/ */(/*//*,..,*(#%%%#((((##%%%%%%%%##((/(((*./((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((( / (( (.*****,,..*(#%%%%&%&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&%***/(// (   .....(/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//.*/*.,,*,,,,..,,/(####((((#%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%,,//*,,,.....,,.*//((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((,((#/*,,,,...,,//(((#%&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@(***/( /(.,**/(((//((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((.......,***//**,,,.,,*///(%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@,*(//.*(####/(/#/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((/( .(/**,,,***,,,,....,,,,,*//(&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*,*.//*/#%%##/((#,/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((/(/(// (((((((((((( ..,/(/*//(((((//,.. .,,.,,,*,,,*(#&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&(**//(,/((##(*/%%(/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
((((((((((/(    .**.... ..*****,,,,,,**/**//(##((//,..,,,,,.,,,,,//(#&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&*,*(//,//(((*,#&///((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((/(( ,,..,***,****,*......//(((((***/**/((((///,..,,,,,.,,,,*(((#%&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&&@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#**.((/*/((/*,*#&/ ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((( ,.,(//(((/,,**,*/*///.,**,,,...**//,*(((((/*...,,,,,.,,,,*(((#%&&@@@@%(/(#@@@@@@@@@/*,,,*(@@@@@@@@@@@@%,** (.*/(/*,,/&&//(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((//..*/((((((/(.,,,,,.*/*,*,,,**(/ ,**//,,///((/*...,,,,,.,,,*,/((#%&&@@%/*,.***(@@@@@*,  .,,#@@@@@@@@@@@@/**(//,//(/*.*(#/((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((.(../(((((((/(/(.... ,**,...,,,....,***,,//*////...,,,,,.,,,*,/(##%%&@@((,.   ,*&@@@@&%#(   ,,#@@@@&%%######(/*,(/*////,*//#/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((/(..((( ...,.../((..,..*/***.,..,.,,***,,***////,..,,,,,,,,,*,*(##%%&@@%#%(,,**/@@@@@@@%#%%#//#############(///*(/,*///,,***/(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((/(//.,,..*****../(/(,,*..*//,,*,...,***,,,*,*///,,.,,,,,,,,,***/(((((((((((#####%%%%%&&&%#((((((((//////////****...,**,.*/*./(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((,,*(((/*.,,*.,,,,*.,.,***,,,**,*//*,..,,,,,,,,**,,,******************///////***///////((///(((((((#(***////.((((((( //.,,(//*(//*.(/((((((((((
((((((//(.. (//,.../((((/(.,,**..,,,,*.***,,,,*,,***,..,,,,,,,****,****************////((((((((///************/*///(#(//*,,*/, /(..**//*/(((/*,**(((*(/((((((((
((((((/... ./.,..,,/(((((//(.,*/,...,*//*,,,,,*****//***,,,,**//**///**,*****////((//***//(/*,,****/////((((###(((((##(/*,,,**,**,,,,,,,//**.....,,/((/((((((((
(((((/(..,*,,.   .//(((((((//(..,**..,**,,,.,..,....,,,*****//***//*,,,*///////**,,,,**/(/,,**/((((///***,,,...      .***,,,,.......,*,.*/,,. .,,,,*(/(((((((((
((((((/*     *(///((((((((((((((/,*.(.,,**,,. .,....,*****////**//*********,//*(#(((/,**(/*,,..           .,,**,.,,*******,,         .,.,**,...***,*((/((((((((
(((((((///((/(((((((((((((((((((/(/,*(**,,,,. .*,,,***//////***************,//%&%%&&&(***,  ..,..,,,,,,,..,,....,,,,,,,,*********////**/,,//*******(/(/((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/((*,,(.*,,. ..,****///*****,,,*//**/////*,/(&%#%&&(//*,,,,,,,,,,********,,,,,,,,,*******//(///****///*,*((/*/((/(((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((.,,*,,,*,..  ..**//*,,,,,,*****,,**,***,*/#%%###%(((/***////**//******/*///////////////////////****/((*,,,,,,,*/(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/(.,,,,,,**,...,******,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/(#((/(((///****//(((####%#########%%#########((#((//(((((###(//****//(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((,,*******,.,//******,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,***,,*/(((///(((##%%%%%&%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#%%%%#####((//((###((/*//(/*/(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((/  //,******,*,********,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,****/(((#####((/((((####%###%%#%%%%%%&&%%%%%%%#####(((((#(//((///((*((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((/(/    ,,,,,*******************,,,,,,,,,,,,***************//(((#####(//***//((#####%%%%##%%%%%&&&%%%%#####((/(((((((((/(///,/(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((/(.,,,,,,****,*************,,,,,***,,,,,,,****,*************//(####%#(/*,***///((######((/////((#%%%%%&&%%#(/////(((((((((##(*/(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((//*,,,******************,,*,,,,,,,,***********,************//((((###(//*..*/////////****//(##%%(/.,*/(#%%##((/////////((((#(((/.(((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((,**********************,,,*****************,**************//((##(((/(/*.  .,,,**/(#**&@@@@@@@@@&.,/,*//((////////((((((((/((/(((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((/,***********************,,**************,    .,*,,*******///((##(((((/(/, .,//((#%/&@@@@@@@@@@*.%@@@&(/,,/((((((((((((#(//(#/ ((((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((,,************************,**///////****.       .,***********/((((##((/(#(, .,,,,..   /%@@@@@@@@@/ /@@@@@@@(((((((((//((((////#*(((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((,,******,,..,,************,*/////////**,. ........,*/******//((((####(((##/.           *@@@@@@@&%, .%@@@@@&(((((((/(((///((//(#//((((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((,,***,    ,...,***********,*////*//*/*,,...........*//****////((((###(((#%(*,           ,//,,.        ..,*/((((##((/(/////////((,,.((((((((
((((((((((((((((((((/***,   ,,,,...,**********,*////***//*,,...........,*********/((######(##%#/*,                        .,*/((((((((/(((((///*,*/###(*/((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((***. .,,,,,,...,*********,*////****/*,,.......,,,,,,**,***///(((#####((###((**                      ,((///////(((//(/////***////((//((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((/*, .,,,,,,,....*********,,*//*****//*,...,,**,,,,,,**,,,**///((########%##(/**.                   *////////////(////***///***//((((/(((((
((((((((((((((((((((/,,,.....,,.,,...,**,,****,,*//**///**,,..,**,,,,,..,,,,*****////(((((((#####(/,,,.....            */////////////*****//*****//(((((/((((((
((((((((((((((((((((/.,.......,,,,,..,,,,,*****,,*,,,,,,,*,,.,*,,,,,.....,,*(/(///////((((((######(*,,*(%&&&//((#(((#//***///////*****////**///(((/((//,(/(((((
(((((((((((((((((/(**,,,,,...,*,,,,,,,,,**,,**,..,......   .,,,,,...,,,,..,***////((#(((//////(#(((//,,,*/##/////////,,**********//////////(///////**/(#.((((((
((((((((((((((((((//....,,,,,**,,...,,..  .......       ...,,,,,,..****,,,,,*,,**///((((#((//*/((((//**,,,,,**//**,,,,****,**//****//////(((//*,,,*//*/(/./((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((,,,,,**,,,.,,,,.  ....,............,,,,....,,..,..,,*******((((//////////((((/**,,,......,,,,**/(((////**////(((((/*....,.,*////(*(((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((*,*****.,,...,,,.  ....,........ ...,,,,....,,,........,,***((((#((//(((//(##(###(////////((((/((((/////////////*..  .....,.****///(/(((
((((((((((((((((((((((//,****//,,..,,,,.  ....,........, .,,,,,....,,..,,..,,...   ..**//((#((((((((((#(((///////(//(((((((((((///*,... ......,..,.,****//(/(((
((((((((((((((((((((((//,,*****,....,,..  ....,....(*,,/(..,**,,...,,,.....,...    .,,,...,*//(#((((/(((((((///(((((((((((((//*..    ..    ........,,**,**(/(((
(((((((((((((((((((((((/,,***,,........  ........./(///(//,,*,,,,....,,,,,,,...   .,,,,,.......,*/((((((((#(((/((#((((//*,.......    ..........,...,,,,,*..((((
((((((((((((((((((((((((,,,,,,... ....   .  .... *(((((((//.,**,,,......,,... .....,*,,,.....   ..  .  ..,,,,,... .,****...........   ............,,,,,,,*/((((
                        ..,...                    ......    .,,,,,,....         .,,,,,......       (//////(/(//((((((((((/..,,.....       .....,,,,,,,,,(/(((((
                                               ...............,,*,,,,,....    ..,,,,...........,*, (/(((((((((((((((((((///...,..........,,,,,,,,,,....(/((((((
                                                               .,,,,,,,.......,,,........       .           (((((//(/((((((/*..........,,,,,,,...... /(((((((((
.                                                                ...............                                    .. /(((((((      ......       ,((/(((((((((
      ..                                                              ....                                                  .........            ....((((((((((
((((/////////////((((*.,                                                       ...........                                                   ./((((((/(((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((//(((** .                                                                          .. .,////(/(((((((((((((((((((////(/(((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((//((((/(/((((((((((((((((((/(/////////(/////((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
EOF
    # mater's a helpful feller, so
    git checkout master
    else
        git "$@"
    fi
}

# Inherit whatever command completions you have set up for `git`
compdef get_yer_maters=git

# Use your new function instead of git
alias git=get_yer_maters
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Doing this broke my cool zsh git completion. To fix it, do this:
`compdef get_yer_maters=git` before `alias git=get_yer_maters`.

This will make sure that your new function gets the same completions that `git` did.